# How get properties for a inherits class by this condition

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, bindingflags

I have a `Person` class that inherits `PersonBase` and this second class inherits `EntityBase`:

```
public class Person : PersonBase
{        
   virtual public string FirstName { get; set; }
   virtual public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

And

```
public class PersonBase : EntityBase
{        
   virtual public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class EntityBase : IEntity
{    
   public virtual long Id { get; protected set; }
   public virtual string Error { get; protected set; }
}
```

I need to get list of properties of `Person` and `PersonBase` classes :

```
var entity = preUpdateEvent.Entity;

foreach (var item in entity.GetType().GetProperties()) //only FirstName & LastName & GroupName
{
   if (item.PropertyType == typeof(String))               
      item.SetValue(entity, "XXXXX" ,null);
}
```

Now `GetProperties()` is include : `FirstName, LastName, GroupName, Id, Error` but I need only own Person properties namely : `FirstName, LastName, GroupName`

Of Course I has been used below code but it is not suitable for me
 because it is only  include properties of `Person` class.

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                  BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

How can I get the properties that are only defined on `Person` and `PersonBase` classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic solution to your problem, in the form of an extension method:

```
public static PropertyInfo[] GetPropertiesUpTo<T>(this Type type, BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance)
{
    return type.GetProperties(flags)
               .Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(T) || p.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
               .ToArray();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetPropertiesUpTo<PersonBase>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.DeclaringType == typeof(PersonBase) || p.DeclaringType == typeof(Person));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to recursively find it by going through `typeof(Person).BaseType` which will return `PersonBase`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell `GetProperties()` "how many" classes to get properties from - it either gets the properties for the current class and all classes it extends/inherits-from, or (by using [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx)) it can get just the current class's properties.

You can use two calls to get the properties:

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                  BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
var parentProperties = typeof(PersonBase).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                  BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

Or filter on the full list returned without using `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`, using each property's [`DeclaringType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype.aspx) value. This can be done with `linq` as Lee has shown, or by looping through the full list of properties and using an `if-statement`:

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)) {
    if ((pi.DeclaringType == typeof(PersonBase)) || (pi.DeclaringType == typeof(Person))) {
        properties.Add(pi);
    }
}
```